# How to install additional system components in Xcode 8

Tags: ios, xcode, comments

I installed Xcode 8.0 and the comment selection command key + / stopped working.

In Xcode 8 release notes it mentions source editor extensions and says this:

To use the Editor's Comment/Uncomment Selection and Add Documentation commands—as well as other installed Xcode Extensions—on OS X version 10.11, launch Xcode and install additional system components, then restart your Mac. (26106213)

How does one do this?

Note that this doesn't seem to be the same as "Additional_Tools_for_Xcode_8"

Also because the command + / is grayed in Xcode's Editor->Structure menue some said to run: sudo /usr/libexec/xpccachectl
I did this and now the command + / is not grayed but still doesn't work.
Can anyone also elaborate on what the xpccachectl executable is doing?

Thanks.

Comment: This somewhat relates: http://www.russbishop.net/xcode-extensions  also https://twitter.com/ericasadun/status/743866189894455296

Comment: have you solved this ? facing same issue

Comment: no, it sometimes works and other times doesn't work.